# Global Variable from Minified File is undefined in js files?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

[image: folder-structure]

I have the above structure that I am using to serve the HTML files via Node.
In my `index.html` I have two script tags:

```
<script src = "phaser.min.js" ></script>
<script src = "game.js" ></script>
```

I have a `server.js` which handles the request sent to the server and runs the server on a port.
First I am loading the minified file and then I am loading the `game.js` file.

Current Behaviour :

`game.js`

```
class playGame extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("PlayGame");
    }
}
```

The error thrown in the browser is  `Phaser is not defined`.

If I directly open the file `index.html` without serving it via `npm start` command whole code works fine and no error is thrown.

Comment: You should probably share more of the code, for someone else to be able to help you.
The issue could be that your `Phaser` class isn't exported/imported properly.

Comment: Either `phaser.min.js` doesn't register that global or the file is failing to load. There's no way to tell which from the code and the debugging information you've provided in the question. (The Network tab of the developer tools in your browser will help).

Comment: In the network tab both the files are getting downloaded.
`phaser.min.js` and `game.js`

Comment: @Quentin I have removed the tag `minified.js`.
I have used the `phaser.min.js` so it would by default export Phaser variable globally.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your `server.js` file, it's possible you're not serving phaser as a static file. Another final option might be to just use a CDN as the source.